# Array duplicate detection in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I code this program that ask for the user to.
Enter the number of integers to sort: (e.g) 3

```
input 1: 3
input 2: 3
input 3: 3
```

using boolean found = false; in my code in order to search a number in array.
If the user will input:
"Enter a number to be search in array:" (e.g) 3

The index for that number will be display. I correctly coded that part.
but it turns out that my program checks the first element,whenever I enter the same number. But If I enter like , 3,4,5. then search for 5. My program display the index of number 5.

So, what if I have duplicates? What should I use. If you look at my code bellow.

```
boolean found = false;
System.out.println("Enter a number to be search in array:");
    jj = jhay.nextInt();

    for (gremio = 0; gremio < yahj; gremio++) 
    {
        if (array[gremio] == jj) 
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found)
    {
        System.out.println("Found at index " + gremio);

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not found!");
    }
```

numbers of integers to sort : 3
input: 3
input: 5
input: 5

search integer : 5

"Found at index " : 1

but why my program cannot find index 2?

This is the whole code of my Program.

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class JavaApplication1 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int yahj, gremio, jj, temp;
    boolean found = false;
    Scanner jhay = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the number of integers to sort:");
    yahj = jhay.nextInt();

    int array[] = new int[yahj];

    System.out.println("Enter " + yahj + " integers: ");

    for (gremio = 0; gremio < yahj; gremio++) 
    {
        array[gremio] = jhay.nextInt();
    }

    for (gremio = 0; gremio < yahj - 1; gremio++) 
    {
        for (jj = 0; jj < yahj - gremio - 1; jj++) 
        {
            if (array[jj] > array[jj + 1]) 
            {
                temp = array[jj];
                array[jj] = array[jj + 1];
                array[jj + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Sorted list of integers in ascending order:");

    for (gremio = 0; gremio < yahj; gremio++) 
    {
        System.out.println(array[gremio]);
    }

    for (gremio = 0; gremio < (yahj - 1); gremio++) 
    {
        for (jj = 0; jj < yahj - gremio - 1; jj++) 
        {
            if (array[jj] < array[jj + 1]) 
            {
                temp = array[jj];
                array[jj] = array[jj + 1];
                array[jj + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
     System.out.println("Sorted list of integers in descending order:");

    for (gremio = 0; gremio < yahj; gremio++) 
    {
        System.out.println(array[gremio]);
    }

    System.out.println("Enter a number to be search in array:");
    jj = jhay.nextInt();

    for (gremio = 0; gremio < yahj; gremio++) 
    {
        if (array[gremio] == jj) 
        {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found)
    {
        System.out.println("Found at index " + gremio);

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not found!");
    }     
}
```

}

Comment: because you are printing `System.out.println("Found at index " + gremio);` outside of the loop, aswell as you `break` out of it if you have a match.

Comment: Should your program output both index 1 and 2 in the [3,5,5] example, or only 2 (i.e. the last index containing the requested number)

Comment: yes. my program should update both index 1 and 2 and etc. whenever it detects the same number

Comment: could you add a sample input and desired output example? i might be able to help you

Comment: @vicky96

"Enter the number of integers to sort" : (e.g) 3
input 1: 3
input 2: 3
input 3: 3

Enter a number to be search in array: (e.g) 3
    Found at index 0
    Found at index 1
    Found at index 3

Answer (score 0):

The `break;` statement in your `if` condition breaks the loop as soon as you find the first match. So the loop does not continue any further and the rest of the array element are not searched any more.

```
  if (array[gremio] == jj) 
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
```

if you need to print all the possible matches you can use this code:

```
boolean found = false;
System.out.println("Enter a number to be search in array:");
jj = jhay.nextInt();

for (gremio = 0; gremio < yahj; gremio++) 
{
    if (array[gremio] == jj) 
    {
        found = true;
        System.out.println("Match found at index " + gremio);
    }
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("Not found!");
}
```

Comment: i tried to remove the break; but the output is still the same.

Comment: It can be done by only removing the break statement .If you remove the break statement only you will still get only one result. You need to print all the match result in the loop to show all the results.

Comment: it did not work bro. I tried to enter 2 numbers 
eg: 44 and 44.

it only says that : "Match found at index" 0.

Comment: then there must be any issue with your condition of for loop. "gremio < yahj" You can use gremio < array.length . So your for loop will be as:

Comment: i tried to change it. still the same. I cant figure it out.

Comment: can you please post your complete code what it has become now after the edit

Comment: well according to your code it should work fine if you remove the break; condition .

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want.

If you want to output every match, put the print inside the loop and only display `not found` if you didn´t had a match after the loop.

```
boolean found = false;
System.out.println("Enter a number to be search in array:");
jj = jhay.nextInt();

for (gremio = 0; gremio < yahj; gremio++) 
{
    if (array[gremio] == jj) 
    {
        found = true;
        System.out.println("Found at index " + gremio);
    }
}
if (!found) {
    System.out.println("Not found!");
}
```

If you only want the last match you could exclude the `break` out of the loop which would give you the last index.

```
boolean found = false;
System.out.println("Enter a number to be search in array:");
jj = jhay.nextInt();

for (gremio = 0; gremio < yahj; gremio++) 
{
    if (array[gremio] == jj) 
    {
        found = true;
    }
}
if (found)
{
    System.out.println("Found at index " + gremio);

}
else
{
    System.out.println("Not found!");
}
```

Comment: @jasslol you could try to print each number of the array in the loop, indepentend of the index. Maybe you are missing values and the mistake has it´s origin somewhere else in your code (maybe value assignment)

Comment: btw. the code that I posted above is not the whole code of my Program.

Answer (score 0):

I used your code, made a few changes, added some test variables of my own... refer this code to make changes to yours.

```
    Scanner jhay = new Scanner(System.in);
    int gremio;
    int[] array = {3, 5, 5};
    boolean found = false;
    System.out.println("Enter a number to be search in array:");
    int jj = jhay.nextInt();

    for (gremio = 0; gremio < array.length; gremio++) {
        if (array[gremio] == jj) {
            found = true;
        }

        if (found) {
            System.out.println("Found at index " + gremio);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not found!");
        }

        found = false;
    }
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Since your array is sorted, you might want to use binary search to return all the indexes where the search value is located:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<Integer> binSearch(T[] array, T value) {
    List<Integer> found = null;
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(array, 0, array.length, value, Comparator.naturalOrder());
    if (index < array.length() && array[index].compareTo(value) == 0) {
        found = new ArrayList<>();
        found.add(index);
        for (index++; index < array.length; index++) {
            if (array[index].compareTo(value) == 0) {
                found.add(index);
            }
            else break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

**Note** [Comparator.naturalOrder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--) is only found in Java 8 API, otherwise you would have to supply a custom comparator class to use this